# How do I find out power requirements from AC / DC specs?

Tags: power, watts

I have a device with the following AC / DC specs:

100—240V, ~2 amps,50—60 Hz
24V DC @ 6.25 amps

[click to see device](https://store.makerbot.com/replicator2.html)

How to get power in Watts from this information?

Also, for a second device:
100-240V
1.5A 50/60Hz
60W

[click to see device](http://formlabs.com/pages/tech-specs)

Where did they get 60 Watts from? Doesn't Power = V * I?

Thanks!

Comment: The question would be clearer, if you provide details about what kinds of devices these are.

Answer (score 2):

Power = V x I x *PF*

Where PF = [power factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor). For "normal" loads (e.g. resistive) PF = 1, so Ohm's law in its most familiar form applies. That covers all the typical educational introductory laboratory test cases so we start there to avoid confusing people needlessly.

### For your first device...

You can tell 2 pieces of information (approximately) for your first device:

#### 1. Efficiency

Efficiency is broadly defined as out/in. Here, Pout/Pin. 
Pin,min = 100*2*1; Pout,max = 24*6.25*1; Ergo, the best possible efficiency is 75% because we assumed the least amount in for the most amount out at the best power factor (1).

#### 2. Maximum Safe (supposedly) Output Power

Use your original concept of an assumed PF=1. Volts * Amps * PF = Watts. Interestingly when you are *assuming* PF=1, rather than *knowing/claiming* PF=1, the unit used is called *Volt-Amps* (VA) to illustrate this. If you google for consumer UPS (battery backup), you will observe that they are almost universally rated this way.

So a valid conclusion is that this unit can output up to 24*6.25=150VA.

### For your second device...

If the specs can be believed (always test if it's mission critical). They are claiming that the device is reasonably efficient and the output voltage is either known (indicated somewhere else) or adjustable (range should be published somewhere).

Therefore, the output current is not as important as the output power since there is a relationship between output voltage and current that has a (roughly) fixed product (power). They have specified the *input* current, voltage, and frequency, but the output power.

Incidentally, the numbers look a bit off to me since input power is >150W and output power is only 60W... Could you post a photo of the label?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will add links for the devices in the original question. Sorry I don't own the device so I can't take a picture of the labe.

Answer (score 1):

For the first device, 24V × 6.25A = 150W, which is probably close to the actual power required. The AC specs of 100-250V suggest that it has a "universal input" SMPS, and the 2A would be the maximum current drawn from the line, which would occur at the lowest input voltage. The fact that this multiplies out to 200W is a combination of the (in)efficiency of the power supply, coupled with what is probably a poor power factor as a result of harmonic distortion of the current waveform.

For the second device, they state directly that it requires 60W. Again, this would seem to have a universal-input power supply, and the 150W implied here again represents the worst case in terms of efficiency and power factor.

The AC current value specified in both cases may also represent the size of fuse used, which would have some "margin" above the actual power requirements of the device in order to avoid nuisance trips that might be caused by short-term (but harmless) current surges.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! More information on the devices in the original post.