# How much power does 5V and 6A provide in Watts?

Tags: power-supply, power, output

Am I right in concluding that a unit that says 5 V and 6 A on the back supplies 30 W of power? Or is it that it requires 30 W to be powered? And if so, how do i calculate how much power the unit supplies (output)?

Comment: Is this a power supply or something else?

Comment: It is connected to a mains power socket and is providing power to other devices. Basically, it's a trickle charger for mobile phones.

Answer (score 1):

If it a power supply, then it means that you can draw a max of 6A at 5V (i.e. 30W). If it is a device which requires electrical power to operate, then it means that the device requires 6A at 5V to operate (again, 30W).

Note that if it is a 5V power supply, 6A is the max amperage it can provide. The amperage it actually provides to your circuit depends on the circuit's power requirements. So if you hook up a microcontroller to the power supply, for example, it would only a fraction of 1A.

Comment: It's kind of both...it needs power to operate and plugs into the mains power socket; however, it supplies power to other devices too. If you can help, that would be great.

Comment: Well, that means it's a power supply. Nothing can spontaneously generate power. Everything needs an input energy source to run, and presumably has an output energy pathway. So you plug the power supply into mains, and there is some sort of transformer inside the supply's enclosure which steps down the voltage (from your mains voltage level) and tells you the max amperage you can draw. So as far as I understand from your description, your device is most certainly a power supply. Hope that helps.

Comment: If my answer satisfied you, feel free to select it as the best one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/52577/16519) is similar. I'll adjust it for your specific question.

The answer is, if it is a power supply, 30W is the maximum power it can supply. If it is a device, 30W is the maximum power it *might* consume. Maximum powers are designed for safety and should represent the extreme end of the edge cases. The device will typically turn on and run with less, but that is the size of the power source you must maintain for guaranteed normal operation.

Power = V x I x *PF*

Where PF = [power factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor). For "normal" loads (e.g. resistive) PF = 1, so Ohm's law in its most familiar form applies. That covers all the typical educational introductory laboratory test cases so we start there to avoid confusing people needlessly.

If you assume PF=1, Volts * Amps * PF = Watts. Interestingly when you are *assuming* PF=1, rather than *knowing/claiming* PF=1, the unit used is called *Volt-Amps* (VA) to illustrate this. If you google for consumer UPS (battery backup), you will observe that they are almost universally rated this way.

Comment: It's kind of both...its a device that supplies power to mobile phones...it requires power to then power mobile phones. It provides a steady trickle charge; however, I'm trying to work out how much it actually provides.

Comment: Why are you trying to work that out? You might get better answers from the community, if you ask about your ultimate question. So, what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to prove that a product my company uses is not fit for purpose to then create a business case for an alternative supplier. I'm not well versed in electricity so was hoping to find an answer here. My company has live phones on display in stores; however, you will find at least 30% of the phones off and I believe it's because the product they're using is not supplying enough power to the handsets via the trickle charging unit. Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: Sure. That's easy enough to prove with a volt-meter. Just measure the output voltage. If it is below 4.8V or so, it is overloaded.